# Can't Locate A Link Using CSS Selectors

Tags: c#, css, selenium, selenium-webdriver, css-selectors

I'm trying to use Selenium to collect some results off google but the CssSelector I'm using keeps returning "No element found".

Here's my code.

```
//Open google page
IWebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));
driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("https://www.google.com/search?q=cheese");
wait.Until(driver1 => ((IJavaScriptExecutor)driver).ExecuteScript("return document.readyState").Equals("complete"));

//Get image link
IWebElement image_link = driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("a[class='q qs']"));
```

The exception occurs on the last line and the anchor I'm trying to get is written as such on the webpage.

```
<a class="q qs" href="/search?q=cheese&amp;client=firefox-a&amp;hs=YWQ&amp;rls=org.mozilla:en-US:official&amp;source=lnms&amp;tbm=isch&amp;sa=X&amp;ei=ewL9U-S5FNGpyATTl4CgCA&amp;ved=0CAgQ_AUoAQ">Images</a>
```

What's going wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I think getting the [link by text](http://docs.seleniumhq.org/docs/03_webdriver.jsp#by-link-text) would be *more reliable and explicit* here:

```
IWebElement image_link = driver.FindElement(By.LinkText("Images"));
```

Comment: Seems like a useful thing to know about. Thanks for the tip but I'm still curious as to why my CssSelector isn't working as I need to use them in places where there isn't any predictable link text.

Comment: @user3875080 well, I tried the same code but with selenium python bindings - it worked for me. Let's try the following selector: `a.q.qs`.

Answer (score 0):

You're not passing the css selector a css class. You're passing it an element selector filtered by attribute. Try:

```
By.CssSelector(".q.qs")
```

Answer (score 0):

https://www.simple-talk.com/dotnet/.net-framework/xpath,-css,-dom-and-selenium-the-rosetta-stone/

Refer the above link. 
Just try this code.

```
IWebElement image_link = driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("a.q qs"));
```

And using xpath

```
IWebElement image_link = driver.FindElement(By.Xpath("//a[@class='q qs']"));
```